# Error: oci_bind_by_name() expects parameter 1

Tags: php, oracle

i get the following error message with this code section and i can't explain it. Maybe you have a tip for me?

> PHP Warning: oci_bind_by_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var2/www/dk/testing/impuls/mods/mod_newIdea/page_submitIdea.php on line 190, referer: https:...

```
    $ideStart = time();
            $counter = 0;
            $status = "new";

            $stid = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO IDM_HISTORY (HIS_UNIX_TIME_START, HIS_PERSNUM, HIS_STATUS, HIS_HASH) VALUES (:HIS_UNIX_TIME_START, :HIS_PERSNUM, :HIS_STATUS, :HIS_HASH)");
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':HIS_UNIX_TIME_START', $ideStart);
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':HIS_PERSNUM', $_SESSION['ac_persnr']);
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':HIS_STATUS', $status);
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':HIS_HASH', $_SESSION['hash']);

            oci_execute($stid);
            oci_free_statement($stid);
```

Comment: you should use var_dump($stid) to see if is null or not.

Comment: You need to add error checking. You can't assume that `oci_parse()`, or most other database functions, can't possibly fail.